# focus select html element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to promt native select element using JS?

http://jsfiddle.net/dqa0p30q/

```
$('#img').click(function() {
  alert('');
  $('select').trigger('change');
  $('select').focus()// this won't work too
})
```

Comment: where is the change you trigger?

Comment: check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dqa0p30q/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
$('#img').click(function() {
  alert('');
  $('select').trigger('change');
  $('select').focus()
  selectbox = $('select')[0]
  selectbox.size = selectbox.options.length;
})
```